# CSS @media for distinguishing mobile and desktop devices

Tags: html, css

I tried setting two different styles for a website using @media. But it always loads the desktop view no matter if I use a phone or a computer.

```
/* desktop screen */
@media (min-width: 801px){
   content desktop
}
    
/* mobile screen */
@media (max-width: 800px){
  content mobile
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer to your question is: you're using `width` and `device-width` wrong. Change line #169 from:

```
@media (max-device-width: 800px){
```

to:

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
```

If you want to target phones specifically, it is a good idea to look at media queries used by popular frameworks such as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/media-queries.html). You'll find that many target much smaller sizes such as `320px` or `480px` as opposed to `800px` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is CSS media queries distinguish features not devices. So you can try to figure out which features correspond to the device you want to refer to. In [this site](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/) you have media queries for iPhones, iPads. So for example:

iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

These queries try to reduce the case to get to an specific device using its features. In [this site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) you have a set of predefined queries for specific devices.

But notice that [the difference between Desktop and Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40708720/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mobile-and-a-desktop-device) might not be so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to add meta in to `<head></head>`

```
<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: These are both metas with the same name. Are they alternatives or why did you put them both, once "content" first, once "name" first?